# My Bravos XL washer shows "drn" error on all cycles except rinse?spin

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine

I have a Maytag Bravos XL washer. After a recent power outage it started showing "drn" (drain) error during every cycle except the rinse/spin cycle. The washer stops with the drn code and the only way to get it re-started is to unplug and restart with rinse/spin cycle.

A certified Tech checked it out and said there was no blockage either in the drain pipe or the pump. But after his departure it happened again.

Can anyone suggest a reason for this?

Comment: "After a **recent power outage** it started showing". If it was a brown-out then the circuitry could have been damaged; you could need a new control board. Were you not able to replicate the issue while the tech was present?

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus. The issue starts after about 35 min into a cycle. The tech did not want to wait and seemed pretty sure that it was solved!

Comment: I hope you didn't pay them already :-/. If you can then get the issue on video and try to get them to come back.